# How to update node.js version v4.2.1 to latest version on windows/Ubuntu

Tags: node.js

I need one help.I need to migrate the Node.js version to latest version for both windows and Ubuntu.Now I an using version `v4.2.1`.I need it to update to the very latest version.Please provide me the steps to do this for both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: use `npm install -g n` and then `n latest`

Comment: Is this both for windows and Ubuntu.?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: @satya no, might not work for windows, use Bhansa's link for windows